# Electron: app.on('ready') never gets called

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron

I am trying to run electron app with TypeScript and webpack.
I have this `main.ts` file and compiled `main.js` file.

I edited `main.js` so that i can see if ready is called.

main.ts

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import * as url from 'url';
import * as path from 'path';

let win: Electron.BrowserWindow = null;


console.log('start');
console.log(app.isReady);
app.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('ready');
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../', 'no.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
  }));
});
```

main.js

```
console.log('main.js -- start');
exports.ids = [3];
exports.modules = {

/***/ 18:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const electron_1 = __webpack_require__(19);
const url = __webpack_require__(20);
const path = __webpack_require__(21);
let win = null;
console.log('before ready');
electron_1.app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready');
    win = new electron_1.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../', 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true,
    }));
});


/***/ }),

/***/ 19:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("electron");

/***/ }),

/***/ 20:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("url");

/***/ }),

/***/ 21:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("path");

/***/ })

};;
console.log('main.js -- finish');
```

When I run `./node_modules/.bin/electron .` , my console shows

```
> electron .

main.js -- start
main.js -- finish
```

And nothing happens. no window will be opened.

Here is my folder structure.

```
.
├── build
│   ├── index.js
│   └── main.js
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── main.ts
└── webpack.config.js
```

Also I wrote `"main": "build/main.js",` on my `package.son` file.

My environments

OS: Mac 10.10.5
electron: 1.6.11
node: v8.2.1
webpack: 3.0.0

Thank you for reading. I will appreciate any help!!

P.S.
Here is my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.ts',
    index: './src/index.ts',
    template: './src/memo.vue',
    memo: './src/memo.vue'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common'
    })
  ],
  target: 'electron-main',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.vue', '.js'],
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
      ,
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        options: {
          fix: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Webpack wasn't meant for compiling nodejs or electron scripts. I would advise just compiling your typescript to javascript. Electron .asar archives will take care of the packing for you.

Comment: @ThomasDevries it was. In fact it specifically has options for node-js and electron targets.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're using the webpack bundle properly with its entry point. the following Works For Me™.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.ts",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "index.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      loader: "ts-loader"
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules:[
      "node_modules"
    ],
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"]
  },
  target: "electron-main"
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as electron from 'electron';

electron.app.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("electron's body is ready... ");
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron ."
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Even if I do the extra step of having an extra file `main.ts` and `import "./main.ts"` in the `index.ts` it still works.

Comment: Thanks, i uploaded my webpack config file. but I could not find major difference between 2 files..  i think i properly set my target to electron-main.
and still having trouble

Comment: remove the main.ts from the entry points; then have `index.ts` `import "./main.ts"`

Comment: I removed main.ts from web pack.config and modified index.ts. however electron says it could not find main js file specified in package.json(i tried build/main.js and build/index.js but both won't work...). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that since the ready event only fires once it can be missed. I used the `app.whenReady()` to get around that.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appwhenready

Comment: `app.whenReady` is definitely less of a footgun.